# Multiple DNS suffix resolution over VPN with split tunneling?

Tags: windows, vpn, dns

I'm a remote worker of a company that use an AD domain: `mycorp.local`

I've set up a VPN connection to the corporate network (Windows VPN). This connection uses split tunneling to avoid routing all traffic through the VPN connection.

This is working as expected. Resolutions of `*.mycorp.local` use the remote corporate internal DNS.

However, my company have a public domain `mycorp.com`. I would like to resolve internal addresses of computers on this domain. Actually, there are some resources on this domain, not yet published to the internet.

But when I `nslookup demo.mycorp.local`, I get the resolution of the public DNS not the internal DNS.

Is there any way to setup local DNS client to resolve multiple DNS suffixes with my VPN DNS server?

I'm working with W10 64 Enterprise.